# Get script to execute at startup

Tags: debian, cron

I have a script to set mouse 3 button to scroll:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-prop "PixArt USB Optical Mouse" "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1
xinput set-prop "PixArt USB Optical Mouse" "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 2
```

Which is working when I execute it manually:

```
./mouse3.sh
```

But it does not set mousebutton 3 to scroll on reboot using crontab.

`crontab -e`

```
@reboot /home/bera/script/mouse3.sh
```

`sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

```
Dec 18 14:42:45 corsair cron[547]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Dec 18 14:42:45 corsair CRON[574]: (bera) CMD (/home/bera/script/mouse3.sh)
Dec 18 14:42:45 corsair CRON[549]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Dec 18 14:45:01 corsair CRON[2203]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: When your `@reboot` `cron` job runs, there's no X server running to accept the request. `$HOME/.config/autostart` would be a better place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Session and Startup" (Debian 11, xfce) I added an entry with a command that is just the path to the script:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

makes no sense to run it via cron. You don't want it to run at regular intervals, you need it to run as soon as you log in to a graphical session. `cron` can't even know about the graphical session at all!

So, use your desktop environment's "startup tasks" settings tool (however that might be called). Most environments will honor freedesktop/XDG recommendations to look into `~/.config/autostart`.